# How does Work done by external force gets COMPLETELY converted to potential energy when there is friction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, friction, spring

I was solving this question and ended up getting an incorrect result. So this is the answerkey provided .

[image]

So I noticed that the author explains work done by friction is converted completely to potential energy in the spring and the main reason behind this is because the question mentions "A force F drags **slowly**...".

What I think: Since it is dragged slowly, the friction acting upon it will be limiting friction which would indeed be stronger than the kinetic friction if it was dragged fast. So then work done by friction would ofcourse be present right?
So I wanted to know how the author can say the Work Done by external force gets completely stored as Potential energy in spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When friction is present between two bodies, energy is dissipated as heat if one body is moving relative to the other. But if the two bodies are static relative to one another then no energy is dissipated as heat i.e. static friction itself does not "consume" any energy.

Since B is not sliding over A, and there is no friction between A and the ground, then no energy is dissipated as heat. Since we are told A and B are moving slowly we can assume that the kinetic energy of A and B is negligible. So all of the work done by the force F goes into stretching the spring.